# Testing repository with DbContext - mocking issue concerning IDbSet

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I am trying to test a repository that uses DbContext

The issue I am running into is that DbCOntext wants to return DbSet for certain types

I can't even mock IDbSet as it has a PRIVATE CTOR?!?!?!

How is everyone getting over this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of an adapter or wrapper. The DbContext is third party code. Your code should hide this behind an abstraction, remember this is just an implementation detail about how the internals of your system works. You should be free to change this at any time.

```
public class ThatsHardToTest
{
    // Private constructors, slow start up time etc...

    public int AlwaysReturnOneExceptInSuperRareScnearios()
    {
        // Complex logic.
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Now if we want to test our code when the above method goes wrong, e.g database system is offline. I don't want the test to hit the database, so we need an adapter around this third party code. I would either make an interface or base class.

```
public class MyTestAdapter : IExampleAdapter
{
    public int ReturnWhateverIWant()
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I would use `MyTestAdapter` for unit testing my code, as I can control what it does. For the production code you simply substitute this with an adapter which delegates to the real production system. For example:

```
public class MyRealAdapter : IExampleAdapter
{
    public int ReturnWhateverIWant()
    {
        return new ThatsHardToTest().AlwaysReturnOneExceptInSuperRareScnearios();
    }
}
```